# Displaying Database Record MySQLI

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to display a record from my database, however the page appears blank and doesn't display the data I am expecting. The code follows below:

```
<?php 
    $mysqli = new mysqli(localhost, root, USERPASS, DBNAME);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE userID= '" . $_SESSION["sess_uid"] . "'";           
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
    $row   = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

    echo $row['userQuestion'];
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Replace `echo $row['userQuestion'];` with `var_dump($result); var_dump($row);` and tell us what you see.

Comment: A blank page in PHP always means "go look in your error log". Turn up error reporting and display errors on screen always in development. Quote your connection strings as strings (though that's only a notice, not an error) `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Missing array keys will be displayed, and you'll get some hints of where to begin. (start by verifying your connection succeeded in the first place)

Comment: Did you forget `session_start()`?

Comment: Not much code to go on. Where/how is `$_SESSION["sess_uid"]` being assigned? (besides what Marc mentioned)

Comment: i have a session started on a header.php file which works across all other pages so i doubt thats the issue

Comment: When people post code without the mention of any important elements (*which happens 9 times out of 10*), then you have to expect people asking you questions. We're not behind your computer, nor do we have access to your server, you are. 5 lines of code just doesn't "cut it" along with 1 line of text for an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
// there need to be strings arguments here
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', USERPASS, DBNAME);
// sql injection friendly query
$query = "SELECT * FROM `usertable`
    WHERE `userID`='{$_SESSION["sess_uid"]}' LIMIT 1;";
// do we have a result
if($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)){
    // fetch a single row
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        // print the record
        var_dump($row);
    }
}
?>
```

**You need to wrap `'localhost'` and `'root'` as strings.**

Comment: Hi, this displays all the records, within var_dump if I do var_dump($row['userQuestion']); I get null as the result however the content was there when i just dumped $row as a whole

Comment: @user3296793 Array indexes are case sensitive. Right!? Update the `var_dump` result in the Question so we can see it.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_row` returns a numerical array.

You can print the content of the record using `var_dump` or use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead.